# data type mismatch in criteria expression in VB.NET using ms access

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

[image]
[image]

```
Dim query As String 'FOR SQL STATEMENTS INSERT, SEARCH, DELETE, UPDATE
Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand(query, con)
Dim dr As OleDbDataReader
Dim da As New OleDbDataAdapter()
Dim dt As New DataTable()




Private Sub BTNsearch_Click_1(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BTNsearch.Click
   
    Dim vSearch As String = InputBox("Enter Student ID to search name:")

    Dim con As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\admin\Documents\VB.NET PROJECS\InsertDeleteUpdateSearhVbProgram\Database\InsertDeleteUpdateSearch1.accdb")
    
    query = "SELECT * FROM StudentInformation WHERE LRN = " & CInt(vSearch)
    cmd.Connection = con
    cmd.CommandText = query
    da.SelectCommand = cmd
    da.Fill(dt)
    DataGridView1.DataSource = dt

    If dr.Read = True Then
        TextBoxLRN.Text = dr.Item(0).ToString()
        TextBoxFullName.Text = dr.Item(1).ToString()
        ComboBoxGen.Text = dr.Item(2).ToString()
        TextBoxCourse.Text = dr.Item(3).ToString()
        TextBoxSection.Text = dr.Item(4).ToString()
    Else
        ClearTextBox()
    End If
```

I am using the input box to fetch the data from the database and I don't know if the error is my SQL query or the ToString() parameters. I am just a beginner in this field please help me.

these are the errors that I encountered in my code

1. data type mismatch in criteria expression
2. no value given for one or more required parameters

Comment: What is the data type of the `LRN` column? What is the value of `vSearch`?

Comment: Your code doesn't make much sense. You're populating a `DataTable` and binding it to a grid, but you also seem to be trying to use a data reader that you never even create. Even if you fix this current issue, you're still going to get a `NullReferenceException` when you call `Read`.

Comment: Are you sure "short text" is large enough for `gender`? ;)

Comment: Shouldn't need Long Text for those fields. Use Short Text. 255 characters should be enough.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the field order is not correct.

And I would probably NOT have the cmd object etc. global to that form.

I would setup the connection at the applcation level (so, ONE spot, not connection placed all over in code).

Also, does the data grid display, or does that error out also?

Also, in most cases a data adaptor is NOT required to fill a table. You only need the adaport if you going to update that data table - and you not in this example.

So, I would add to settings the connection. That way, not in code, and you get to use the connection builders for you!

So, add a conneciton to your applcation. Here:

[image]

Now, I have a boatload of connecitons - this is a test applcation.

but, you can use the conneciton builder in settings.

So, if we add a new one, like this:

[image]

Hitting the [...], then we get this:

[image]

and change:

[image]

and then DON'T forget to check/set to use JET or ACE -- here:

[image]

(so, make sure you choose ACE if this is a accDB file. If it is a mdb file, then you can use JET).

So, now we have a connection setup. (MUCH better then placing the conneciton string in code).

eg this:
[image]

Ok, so, next up is our code.

we can use this:

```
Public Function MyrstP(cmdSQL As OleDbCommand) As DataTable

    Dim rstData As New DataTable

    Using conn As New OleDbConnection(My.Settings.TestAccess)
        Using cmdSQL
            cmdSQL.Connection = conn
            conn.Open()
            rstData.Load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader)
        End Using
    End Using

    Return rstData

End Function
```

So, now our code becomes this:

```
    Dim vSearch As String = InputBox("Enter Student ID to search name:")

    Dim query As String = "SELECT * FROM StudentInformation WHERE LRN = " & vSearch
    Dim cmdSQL As New OleDbCommand(query)

    Dim rstData As DataTable = MyrstP(cmdSQL)

    DataGridView1.DataSource = rstData

    If rstData.Rows.Count > 0 Then
        With rstData.Rows(0)
            TextBoxLRN.Text = .Item("LRN")
            TextBoxFullName.Text = .Item("Full Name")
            ComboBoxGen.Text = .Item("GENDER")
            TextBoxCourse.Text = Item("Course")
            TextBoxSection.Text = .Item("Section")
        End With
    Else
        ClearTextBox()
    End If
```

In above, does the combo box accept a string, or is it setup to have a ID?

As you can see, setup of a "handy" routine called MyRstP allows you to easy pull a table, and without a lot of code.

Now, of course, out of good habits, we don't want to take user input (ever) and use that for the sql directly.

So, in fact, we should write the above this way:

```
    Dim vSearch As String = InputBox("Enter Student ID to search name:")

    Dim query As String = "SELECT * FROM StudentInformation WHERE LRN = @LRN"
    Dim cmdSQL As New OleDbCommand(query)

    cmdSQL.Parameters.Add("@LRN", OleDbType.Integer).Value = vSearch

    Dim rstData As DataTable = MyrstP(cmdSQL)

    DataGridView1.DataSource = rstData
```

Its also not clear if you using long in Access, or the new big int support. My bets are long, so use oledb integer, which is a 32 bit "long" data type in access.